# Translate columns name into values if set to 1

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

This is my starting df

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("1100455", "1100456", "1100457", "1100458", "1100459", "1100464", "1100467"),
                  S31 = c("0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0" ),
                  S32 = c("0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0" ),
                  S33 = c("1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0" ),
                  S34 = c("0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1" ),
                  S35 = c("0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0" )
)
```

=> result df2

```
 df2
       ID S31 S32 S33 S34 S35
1 1100455   0   0   1   0   0
2 1100456   1   0   0   1   1
3 1100457   0   1   0   0   0
4 1100458   1   1   0   0   0
5 1100459   0   0   0   0   0
6 1100464   0   0   1   0   0
7 1100467   0   0   0   1   0
```

I would like to put the column name (without the S) into each value if equal to 1.
so my result dataframe should be

```
 df_result
       ID S31 S32 S33 S34 S35
1 1100455   0   0  33   0   0
2 1100456  31   0   0  34  35
3 1100457   0  32   0   0   0
4 1100458  31  32   0   0   0
5 1100459   0   0   0   0   0
6 1100464   0   0  33   0   0
7 1100467   0   0   0  34   0
```

Thx for help

Comment: Whoever closed this with the linked answer did not noticed the added layer of complexity in this question. That is the need to "strip" the "S" from the colname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
sapply(names(df2)[2:ncol(df2)], function(name_i){
x <- df2[ , name_i]
x <- ifelse(x == "1", gsub("[^0-9]", "", name_i), "0")
x
})
```

`sapply` goes through each name but the ID, then we extract the column values. `ifelse` replaces values of 1 with the column name number and the not 1 values with 0. You need only to add that to your ID column and name it.